# How to draw a triangle with QUARTZ 2D?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm developing an iPhone app with 3.1.3 SDK.

I'm trying to draw a triangle with transparent fill an 1px black stroke with this code:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, position.X, position.Y - (size.height / 2));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, position.X - (size.width / 2), position.Y + (size.height / 2));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, position.X + (size.width / 2), position.Y + (size.height / 2));
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
```

But I get a black filled triangle.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using the latest version of the SDK! You can still target older operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw a path with transparent fill - then you don't need to fill it - just stroke it when draw, so it seems that your CGContextFillPath method is redundant - remove it:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, position.X, position.Y - (size.height / 2));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, position.X - (size.width / 2), position.Y + (size.height / 2));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, position.X + (size.width / 2), position.Y + (size.height / 2));
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Comment: what is ctx in the above example

Comment: it is reference to current graphic context (CGContextRef), on which you draw in drawRect: method. You usually get it using UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() function