# UITableView custom header (like FoodSpotting app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

[image]

Could somebody explain how this app (FoodSpotting), creates their custom section header? It has a translucent black background, image of the user, and some nice text (loaded up from a server no doubt). My 2 big questions here are:

**1. How does the app get the nice black translucency on the section header?**
 **2. How do they get that little triangle arrow attached to the header?**

I can pretty much figure out everything else based on using a custom view for the section header.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Section header is a UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) just like any other. You can create it as beautiful, as complex, or as elaboarate as you like, using Interface Builder if you want, etc. Your table delegate's `tableView:viewForheaderInSection` is responsible for returning it, just like it is for other cell rows.

As to the little triangle: yeah, this threw us for a bit (we wanted something similar in our app) until we discovered that you can overlap the view with the row by "lying" about it's height: ie `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` returns a value slight less than it actually is. May not be the "right" way, but worked very nicely for us. Like this:

[image]

So the header is actually a perfect rectangle, mostly see-through at the bottom, with a small triangle "peeking" out:

[image]

Tell iOS that the header is 80px high, like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView 
  heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return 80;
  }
```

and it’ll start to draw the “food” row at 80px. Because headers are on top, and because most of header bottom is transparent except for arrow, you should get this effect.

Comment: I completely understand your answer Q1, but could you flesh out your answer to the litte triangle question? I don't really understand how overlapping views will get you a triangle...thanks

Comment: The section header is basically just a view, so you can draw whatever your heart desires, including triangles. You can make it hard for yourself and draw in with Quartz 2D (drawRect:) or just make a triangle in Photoshop, and add a UIImage to the header view among all the other things, such as labels, more images, etc.

Comment: @derek.lo That's probably just the standard back button, but with a different color. Compare it to other back buttons.

Comment: @ThomasW No, he's asking about the triangle below the guy's avatar. Again, something that takes 2 minutes to do in Photoshop ;)

Comment: @runmad and ckhan, I'm still slightly confused by both of your answers. So I get how I run into photoshop and create a small little triangle, but where should I put this triangle/how do I tell IOS to make the bottom 5px of the headerView completely transparent except for the triangle, which in your solution runmad would be a UIImage. Thanks for the answers, I just need a little more clarification! Thanks!

Comment: I'll let @runmad speak to his technique: for ours, there is no separate "little triangle". The header is a perfect rectangle, with bottom 5px totally transparent except for the black triangle portion.

Comment: @ckhan I understand what you're saying I just don't understand how you guys are doing it haha. Could you explain in steps how you might do it your way in IB for instance? Programmatically would also be fine but I'd like to orient all my labels in IB for something like this...

Comment: You don't tell iOS to make the image transparent. The image itself is transparent at the bottom.

Comment: @ckhan is there any code you can provide? (And then I will whole heartedly accept your answer) thanks

Comment: You can make a UIView with IB and then just set the table section header to that view in your code. It's fairly simple http://www.theflashfish.com/?p=91

Comment: @runmad I just need to know how to do the triangle at this point. I'm not understanding how to put all this together with the triangle. I already have it working with a standard UIView with labels and the works, but I can't figure out how you guys are getting the little triangle.

Comment: @derek.lo - more detail, as requested. I think you expecting something more complex than it is  - it's just a transparent image with a bit poking out. Hope that helps!

Comment: Just create a triangle in an image editing software and insert a UIImageView with that triangle image. You could also draw a triangle in draw rect, which will allow you to play around with colours and transparency more easily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545548/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-quartz-2d

Comment: @ckhan ahhhhhh now I understand exactly what you mean. Thanks very much for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the desired result in a different way.  Instead of using `tableView:viewForheaderInSection:` (which doesn't work for me), I added an image view that holds the arrow image as a subview of the header view, and set the frame to be just below the header:

```
// Inside HeaderView.m

UIImageView *arrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.arrowImage];
arrowImageView.frame = CGRectMake(arrowX, frame.size.height, self.arrowImage.size.width, self.arrowImage.size.height);
[self addSubview:arrowImageView];
[arrowImageView release];
```

If you watch closely, there are two files (following-captionbubble-dark.png and following-captionbubble-dark@2x.png) in Foodspotting.app which look exactly like the arrow shown above in the question.  So I guess they might have used a similar technique.  Kudos to the Foodspotting team.