# Is it a was to select section in UITableView and add row for it?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I do not think is possible but is it a way to select a particular section in `UITableView`? I would like to make it possible for user to add a row to that section.

The problem that section normaly has a 22px height, so it is too small to select it, and there is no such a delegate method.

Comment: I think you can try to look at these two questions :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996566/how-to-make-uitableview-header-selectable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307558/uitableview-custom-header-like-foodspotting-app?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use **section header**, there is no such method, but you can add `UIButton` *or* `UITapGestureRecognizer` to section header view and that you can insert row to that section. Use method:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not understand your question correctly but you can use tableview default method to insert row at specific *Section* and *Row* using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method shown below.

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your headerview which you have created using `viewForHeaderInSection` and set tag = section like `yourView.tag = section;` and in your tapGestureSelected method.

```
-(void)tapGestRec:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gest
{
    // Here you will know which section is tapped using gest.view.tag
    NSLog(@"You have selected : %d Section",gest.view.tag);
    [yourTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:gest.view.tag]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: @János you should pass sectionNumber as per your need. like if you have 5 section and you want to insert row at section 1 , row 1 then you should pass 1 for both. or you want to increase your section height?